# Kolmogorov-Smirnov Tests for Laplace destribution R

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov

I have a problem with ks function in R. I have a Laplace Distribution:

```
ldes <- function(y, a) {
  if(y < 0.5) 1/a*log(2*y, 2) 
  else  1/a*log(2*(1-y), 2)
}
a <- 1
set.seed(1)
y = runif(1000, 0, 1)
ld <- ldes(y, a)
```

So, I need to do the ks test, but can't find anything about second parameter that should be in there, like:

```
ks.test(my_lnorm, **plnorm**, mean = -5, sd = 5)
```

for Lognormal Destribution or:

```
ks.test(my_log, **plogis**, location = 2, scale = 3)
```

for Logistics Destribution

Thanks.

Comment: You want to use `ifelse`, not `if`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try some package for the laplace distribution, for example disclap (if it satisfies our need, otherwise some continuous analog).

```
library(disclap)
ks.test(ld, "pdisclap", 0.5) # choose the right value of parameter p (p=0.5 is arbitrary)

One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  ld
D = 0.3333, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

As can be seen from the result of the hypothesis test, the null hypothesis (that the samples are drawn from the same population distribution) is rejected.

```
y2 <- rdisclap(1000, p=0.5) # generate some simulated datapoints
plot(ecdf(ld), xlim = range(c(ld, y2))) # compare ecdfs
plot(ecdf(y2), add = TRUE, lty = "dashed")
```

[image]